# nearest neighbour in dataset Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, classification, knn

I have a Node.js application that saves data to MongoDB.
Given one document, I want to find the most similar document in the database.

My idea is to implement some sort of nearest neighbour algorithm that takes all the records as a training sequence and returns the most similar document (including some sort of percentage on how similar these two documents are.)

E.g. having these records in my database...

```
{ name: "Bill",   age: 10,  pc: "Mac",      ip: "68.23.13.8" }
{ name: "Alice",  age: 22,  pc: "Windows",  ip: "193.186.11.3" }
{ name: "Bob",    age: 12,  pc: "Windows",  ip: "56.89.22.1" }
```

...I want to find the closest document to this one

```
{ name: "Tom", age: 10, pc: "Mac", ip: "68.23.13.10" }
// algorithm returns "Bill", .76
```

Are there any Node modules/implementations that take any kind of objects/parameters and return their nearest neighbour?

Comment: How many records do you have? Are they frequently updated?

Comment: I expect to have a lot (>5000) of records. Once they are saved, they are not updated, but new records may arrive at any time.

Comment: This is not something that will typically be implementes as a stand alone a module. It's more of an algorithmic thing. More of an art. Everybody has different needs. Solution tend to be highly customized. Typically, people use a framework (and a lot of knowledge) to build their solution. Probably the easiest route would be (if you have the resources) to use Solr to index your data. Then query using the MoreLikeThis component: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis

Comment: At a conceptual level, there are two ingredients to this problem. A similarity function that takes 2 documents and returns a number representing how similar they are. And a strategy how often and how much of the entire collection will be reindexed (hint, it's probably not practical to compare all pairs each time you add a new document, this is quadratic time!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example code. It assumes that you can run the search on every request. If you want to modify it, make sure that all similarity functions return a number between 0 and 1.

```
function tokenize(string) {
  var tokens = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length-1; i++) {
    tokens.push(string.substr(i,2));
  }

  return tokens.sort();
}

function intersect(a, b)
{
  var ai=0, bi=0;
  var result = new Array();

  while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )
  {
     if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
     else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
     else /* they're equal */
     {
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }

  return result;
}

function sum(items) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    sum += items[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

function wordSimilarity(a, b) {
  var left   = tokenize(a);
  var right  = tokenize(b);
  var middle = intersect(left, right);

  return (2*middle.length) / (left.length + right.length);
}

function ipSimilarity(a, b) {
  var left  = a.split('.');
  var right = b.split('.');

  var diffs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var diff1 = 255-left[i];
    var diff2 = 255-right[i];
    var diff  = Math.abs(diff2-diff1);

    diffs[i] = diff;
  }

  var distance = sum(diffs)/(255*4);

  return 1 - distance;
}

function ageSimilarity(a, b) {
  var maxAge   = 100;
  var diff1    = maxAge-a;
  var diff2    = maxAge-b;
  var diff     = Math.abs(diff2-diff1);
  var distance = diff / maxAge;

  return 1-distance;
}

function recordSimilarity(a, b) {
  var fields = [
    {name:'name', measure:wordSimilarity},
    {name:'age',  measure:ageSimilarity},
    {name:'pc',   measure:wordSimilarity},
    {name:'ip',   measure:ipSimilarity}
  ];

  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    var field   = fields[i];
    var name    = field.name;
    var measure = field.measure;
    var sim     = measure(a[name], b[name]);

    sum += sim;
  }

  return sum / fields.length;
}

function findMostSimilar(items, query) {
  var maxSim = 0;
  var result = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var sim  = recordSimilarity(item, query);

    if (sim > maxSim) {
      maxSim = sim;
      result = item;
    }
  }

  return result
}

var items = [
  { name: "Bill",   age: 10,  pc: "Mac",      ip: "68.23.13.8" },
  { name: "Alice",  age: 22,  pc: "Windows",  ip: "193.186.11.3" },
  { name: "Bob",    age: 12,  pc: "Windows",  ip: "56.89.22.1" }
];

var query  = { name: "Tom", age: 10, pc: "Mac", ip: "68.23.13.10" };
var result = findMostSimilar(items, query);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works like a charm. However I got a TypeError on `ipSimilarity()`. I solved it by renaming the `sum()` method. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way of doing this would be to calculate a diff between the two documents and the larger the diff, the larger the distance. You could normalize the diff using the maximum possible diff which should give you relative distances that you can compare against each other.

Take a look at this question for calculating a diff on json documents.

[Delta encoding for JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326532/delta-encoding-for-json-objects)

Comment: Would that also take into account, if the ip only changes from 68.23.13.8 to 68.23.13.10 (i.e. a very small change of a property)?
Do you have any code at hand?

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on the diffing algorithm. Most of the algorithms in the question I posted just check any string change, and don't diff individual strings.